# Image will not float: right to the screen because of an overlay & video background

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a video background and I had issues putting text/elements over it, so I created an overlay. This helped me in the short term, but now I can't get an image element to "stick" to the right. I want it to stick to the right regardless of device width.

I have tried to do float: right; This might be an issue with a parent container, but I tried dragging #logo-image outside of the .videoContainer but it wasn't overlayed on top of the video anymore.

I have tried position: absolute; & tweaking the positioning of top and left -- however that doesn't help me keep it stuck on the right.

HTML

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
      <div class="videocontainer">
        <video autoplay="" muted="" loop="" playsinline="" id="vid" preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%" id="homeVideo">
          <source src="photo/water.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

        <h1>
          <img id="logo-image" src="photo/logo.png" align="right" alt="logo">
        </h1>
        <div data-sr class="overlay">
        <h2 id="mantra"> &oline;&oline;&oline;&oline;&oline;&oline;&oline;&oline; <br><br> 
          This is the mantra<br>
        </h2>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.videocontainer { 
    position:relative; 

  }
.videocontainer video {
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}

#homeVideo {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .overlay {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
  } 

#logo-image {
   float: right;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 700px;
   height: 200px;
   margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#mantra {
  margin-left:90%;
  font-size:2vw;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

}
```

I expect to see the #logo-image element floated to the right. If I drag the width of the screen, I want it to still be stuck to the right.

Comment: despite the janky set up here, the image element does stick to the right of the window on load and on resize. what exactly is your issue here?

Comment: It doesn't float to the right; it just sits in a random spot in the middle of the screen

Comment: Here is your code copy pasted into a fiddle. your element is stuck to the right and bottom just as you've asked it to be... https://jsfiddle.net/ty6xzkLo/

Comment: Claire, thank you for your help so far :-)
Ok so take a look at this link. It's really odd but this is what I see: https://gyazo.com/8571b3a8106089254cffe112c797f3ca

Comment: Well then you obviously have more code involved than you posted here. You’ll need to post all the relevant code if you want more help.